# what is this marine creature?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

I found this creature floating in the Mediterranean Sea, probably dead.
I tried looking it up in the Marine Species Identification Portal‬‏ but I couldn't find anything like that. It looks like some kind of jellyfish or hydrozoan.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a blue button jellyfish! they eat zooplankton and are usually found drifting along on currents

they aren't true jellyfish and just like a jellyfish have no blood, brain or nervous system. they aren't usually toxic enough to hurt but can cause irritation to the skin.

they live in warm waters off of Europe and in the golf of Mexico and the Mediterranean.

they are hermaphrodites and have both male and female reproductive parts. they lay eggs which turn into polyps

here is a website I found all about them as I'm not extremely knowledgeable on this species.

https://www.thoughtco.com/blue-button-jelly-porpita-porpita-2291819

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! While your answer seems reasonable, you are more likely to get a positive response if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and (contrary to best practices) requires users to follow a link. ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 